# How to copy an element to another with event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I copy an element to another element along with the event handlers attached.
Normally when we copy one element to another then event handlers are not copied.
How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use clone function with true as parameter.
For more details read its API at http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Check this out :-
http://jsfiddle.net/blunderboy/cRax2/5/

Answer (score 2):

Use `clone(true)`. The `true` parameter is passed to indicate that the original element should be copied including it's events.

```
$("#myElement").clone(true).appendTo("#container");
```

[Clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)